# Expand the function as a taylor series

Tags: probability, taylor-expansion

> > Consider a random variable $A$ whose expectation value is:
> >
> > $$= \sum\limits_{n= 1}^N {a^m_n}p
> > $$
> >     Expand $f(A)$ as a taylor series that is as  $\sum_{j=1}^\infty {c_j}A^j$ for some coefficients $c_j$.

Can someone please explain how to go about this question? How do I expand the function as a taylor series given that only the expectation values are given?

Answer (score 0):

Let me first confirm the following facts:

1. Taylor series is a method to express any real function into a real valued polynomial, but only around a given point.
2. Expected value of a random variable is more of a functional than a function, where the domain of the random variable is mapped into a single, say real, number. We might have some parameters, but these can be considered as constants eventually, i.e., they don't affect the differentiation with respect to the random variable.

In summary, we're talking about Taylor series expansion of a constant function $f(A)=c$, which is more overwhelming (I mean taylor series) than the function itself, right? Unless I'm missing something here, I can say that the Taylor series expansion of a constant function, around any point, is exactly that same constant.

I wished to write you some comments before I answer to clarify more about your question, but unfortunately, my reputation count does not allow me to add comments.